# Can I install more than one instance of ClickHouse database on a single server using different user

Tags: clickhouse

I have ClickHouse already installed on my server(Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) using root, and now can i install it on the same server with another user, and if yes then please provide necessary steps to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want several different ClickHouse instances to work on same server, use separate configuration files for them and provide different data directories (path) and ports to listen.

To specify differen user to run ClickHouse, you could edit its init script (/etc/init.d/clickhouse-server). You could copy it to multiple init scripts to run multiple ClickHouse instances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can install clickhouse with different user. (because installations will have conflicting ports 9000, 8123, etc.)

I believe the best way to do this is use docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server and configure different volume directories and port bindings.

Comment: Recommended, I just used multiple KVMs for a test scenario in which I had to run multiple server but only had one machine. If you want less overhead and possibly less work you could also try with docker/lxc.