# Is 200K rows/second Clickhouse max performance?

Tags: performance, clickhouse

I am testing Clickhouse insert performance and so far I am able to insert over 200K rows/second. To me, this is good. However I see system utilizations is not very high and wonder if I can push more.

CH is in a server with Dual xxx 14 cores @ 2.4 GHz, 56 vCPU with 256GB mem. And insert 1B rows in 1 hour 10 minutes. During that time I see,

- load avg: 23.68, 22.44, 20.32
- %Cpu: 2.93 us, 0.54 sy, 0.14 ni, 95.3 id, 0.96 wa, 0.05 hi, 0.09 si, 0 st
- clickhouse-serv (%CPU, RES): 134.3%, 25.6g

These numbers above are average from "top" of every 5 seconds.
I have observed that clickhouse-server' %CPU usage is never above 200% as if there is a hard limit.

- CH version: 21.2.2.8
- Engine: Buffer (MergeTree) w/ default configuration; w/o Buffer it performs 10% less
- dataset: in json, 2608 B/row, 150 columns
- per insert: 500K rows, which is about 1.2GB
- insert by 20 processes with clickhouse-clients from a different server
- 500K rows/insert and 20 clients give best performance (I have tried different numbers)
- Linux 4.18.x (Red Hat)

Questions:

- Is 200K rows/second (or %200 CPU usage) max per CH server? If not, how can I improve?
- Can I have more than one CH server instances in one server? Will it be practical and give better performance?

In case there is no certain limit on the clickhouse-server side (or I am doing something wrong), I am checking if any others can impose such limit to applications (clickhouse-server).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For having more than one CH server instances:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134403/can-i-install-more-than-one-instance-of-clickhouse-database-on-a-single-server-u

Answer (score 1):

> dataset: in json, 2608 B/row, 150 columns
> insert by 20 processes with clickhouse-clients from a different server

In this case `clickhouse-client` parses JSON and probably CPU utilization is 100% at a different server. You need more inserting nodes to parse JSON.

Comment: Thanks Denny for the input. 
It helps but not much. When the number of clients reaches the certain number the clickhouse-server through exceptions: “too many parts”. That indicate the server can’t keep-up with inputs.
Regardless, I see clickhouse-server never use more than 200% CPU as if there is a hard limit.
In case there is no certain limit on clickhouse-server side (or I am doing something wrong), I am checking if any others can impose such limit to applications.

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/3174#issuecomment-423435071

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings/#parts-to-throw-insert

Comment: Thanks Denny. Good summery about "500K rows/sec". I don't want sacrifice "SELECT" performance so will skip experiments on "parts_to_throw_insert".

In this article, https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/introduction/performance/
it says, "the speed will be from 50,000 to 200,000 rows per second". When the size of row is smaller, the article says, we can get more rows per second. If I convert my dataset to TSV the size is 1K, same to article's dataset size.

Combine all these, it seems getting ~200K rows/sec would be maximum for my case; maybe some more with various tweaks but not significantly.